# Android automatically re-sizing bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

I got a bitmap that's 320 pixels wide and 40 pixels high but the bitmap that i get from loading this resource and decoding with bitmapFactory is 60 pixels high. I check the height immediately after loading the resource so there is no code changing the size.

```
ZitEntity.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.zit1));

public static void setBitmap(Bitmap bit)
{
    inputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bit);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your image in `res/drawable-nodpi/`
see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more info.